# Converting XSL files to CSV files in command line

Tags: command-line, libreoffice

I have a set of XLS files which I want to convert to .CSV retaining the original base name. I found that this code worked best:

```
unoconv -f csv *.xls
```

also there are other ways in this link [converting  xls to csv](http://xmodulo.com/2012/06/how-to-convert-xlsx-files-to-xls-or-csv.html) but I wanted to retain the same name.

After a while it showed me this error

```
Failed to connect to /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin (pid=7779) in 6 seconds.
Connector : couldn't connect to socket (Success)
Error: Unable to connect or start own listener. Aborting.
```

I have tried reinstalling but it does not work. I would like any help where I can retain the name of the xls file and convert it to csv. I am using this code in an R environment and accessing the system terminal.

Comment: What do you mean by retain the name? Why would you want a CSV with a XLS filename?

Comment: I want to convert the xls file to a csv file so that i can use it for my work. for example I wpould like to convert "venkat.xls" to "venkat.csv" without me having to specify the input and output names for it each time.

Comment: Thank you @oli had libreoffice open in another workspace closed it and >unoconv worked.. thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would start by closing LibreOffice. That has caused issues for me in the past with `unoconv` but it has been hard to predict. It's easiest to just let `unoconv` launch its own processing server. If you think you've done that but you're seeing the same error, run `killall soffice.bin` and try again.

In terms of retaining the same name, it does that by default.

```
unoconv -f csv filename.xls
```

That will create a `filename.csv` file. In my mind, this is really desirable because then you know the format of the file (and you won't try to do silly things by accident). And that works for wildcards too:

```
$ ls *.xls
ie_data.xls  QTL_Sample_data.xls  WBC_FTTC_Price_List_Entry_16-Aug-10.xls

$ unoconv -f csv *.xls 

$ ls *.csv
ie_data.csv  QTL_Sample_data.csv  WBC_FTTC_Price_List_Entry_16-Aug-10.csv
```

So you just need to get it up and running and it'll do what you want.